# Count drop-down list box items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

How do you count the number of items returned from a SharePoint list displayed in an InfoPath drop-down list box?

Answer (score 0):

Why not justcount the number of items returned from a SharePoint list?

Refer to the following article about counting listitems in InfoPath:

https://www.spums.be/count-listitems-in-infopath/

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Problem is that I do not want to count repetitive items. That's why I was thinking of counting the items in a the dropdown list box because it actually shows unique items. If you know how I can get unique items only from the items returned from the list then that would be helpful too.